# Why does my javascript keep auto setting my assigned boolean?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to assign a boolean in my dictionary but it keeps auto assigning to "true"
is there a glitch or bug I am unaware of? In the screen shot it shows I set the boolean to false but in the details it says true?? this has been frustrating me.

```
    for(item in data){
        console.log(data[item]["plu_code"])

        var newData = {}
        newData["data"] =  angular.copy(data[item])
        newData["assigned"] = false
        newData["assignedAmount"] = 0
        $scope.addListCopy.push(newData)
        console.log(newData)
    }
    console.log($scope.boxList[0])

    console.log($scope.addListCopy)
    $scope.boxList[0]["addListCopy"] = $scope.addListCopy
```

for my console.logs I get:
[image]

Comment: Is the data you're modifying bound (maybe one way) to the UI such that some checked checkbox or something is acting on it after you do?

Comment: There's probably an error setting the value, as all arrays/bools/objects/functions are 'truthy' if they don't have a value on instantiation. https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: One thing is you have 4 different `console.log`s outputting content. And in the very first line in your console, it does show assigned as being false and assignedAmount as 0.

Comment: @JAAulde turns out my `ng-show="item.assigned=false"` had forced it to false